# MediaPlayer 'prepare();' problem

Tags: android, media-player, prepare

When I use prepare(); on my mediaplayer, a black layout pops up till the mediaplayer is prepared.. I want to change that black screens layout, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prepare();` is a blocking operation, if you dont want to block your UI Thread use [`prepareAsync();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29).
Or use prepare in another Thread

Answer (score 4):

Do all these thing in background thread until media player instance prepared the resource to play and show progress bar upto that time

```
 //progressDialog
    Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaPlayer md=new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                md.setDataSource("Path");
                md.prepareAsync();
                md.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //send message to handler
        }
    });
    th.start();
    //and then dissmiss dialog in handler class
```

**Update**

To know when media player will prepare

```
    md.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Now your media player is ready to play    
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thannk alot. How can I see if the media player is prepared?

Comment: If you use another thread(that is other than UI thread) you dont need to use `prepareAsync()`. `mp.prepare()` is advisable at this scenario.